Slow Load Times for Liferay 7.2 React Portlet
I am using Liferay version 7.2 and have developed a React portlet. The sample React code generated through Blade renders quickly within a few seconds when added to a page. However, after integrating my custom code, which includes multiple components (approximately 25 JavaScript files), the React portlet takes significantly longer to load—about 14-15 seconds. This delay occurs both initially and upon subsequent page reloads, despite caching of related libraries.
Additionally, whenever I add a new library in the package.json file, it increases the load time by approximately 2-3 seconds for each npm package added.
To clarify, the same React code runs efficiently outside of Liferay, indicating that the React code itself is not inherently slow. The issue seems to be specific to the Liferay environment.
I am looking for insights into potential causes for this slowdown and any guidance on how to optimize the load time of my React portlet within Liferay.
Environment Details:
Liferay: 7.2
React: 17.0.2
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
